# capacitor http plugin to avoid pre-flight request

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, capacity

I am trying to do post request to cloud function using capacitor http plugin to avoid triggering pre-flight request. But every time getting error `Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Preflight Did Not Succeed)`

Here is
http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, HttpOptions } from '@capacitor-community/http';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor() { }

  doGet(url) {
    const options: HttpOptions = {
      url
    }
    return from(Http.get(options));
  }

  doPost(url): Observable<any> {
    const options: HttpOptions = {
      url,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer id_token' },
      data: { foo: 'bar', cool: true },
    };

    return from(Http.request(options));
  }
}
```

And
home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../services/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  data = null;
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  nativeCall() {
    this.httpService.doPost('https://xxxxx/cloude_function_name').subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.data = res.data.specials;
    });
  }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: because your angular app is not running on the same domain as your api you cannot avoid having to configure CORS in your Api, that's something all top market browsers implement.

Comment: So there is no way that I can bypass CORS  with changing my request ?

Comment: no... not when you are using a market standard browser.

Comment: Kindly post this as an answer so that the community would find this helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research I found out that we can not bypass CORS in web view even using capacitor-community/http plugin for ionic app.
Reference (https://github.com/capacitor-community/http/issues/28#issuecomment-654932498).

We can use capacitor-community/http plugin to bypass CORS in native app but not in web view.

Comment: I will, After 24 hour I can accept my own answer.

Comment: is adding token dynamically possible in http plugin

Comment: Yes, You can pass token in headers.